# Tibco Active Matrix Business Works mapping flat object structure to a complex structure

Tags: xpath, tibco, businessworks

I am trying to map the input format of my data object to the target format.

The input format is:

```
<Warehouses>
    <Warehouse>
         <ID>WH01</ID>
         <DescriptionEN>Warehouse</DescriptionEN>
         <DescriptionDE>Warenlager</DescriptionDE>
    </Warehouse>
    <Warehouse>
         <ID>WH02</ID>
         <DescriptionEN>Warehouse</DescriptionEN>
         <DescriptionDE>Warenlager</DescriptionDE>
    </Warehouse>
</Warehouses>
```

The target format should be:

```
<Warehouses>
    <Warehouse>
         <ID>WH01</ID>
         <Descriptions>
               <Description>
                      <Language>en</Language>
                      <Text>Warehouse</Text>
               </Description>
               <Description>
                      <Language>de</Language>
                      <Text>Warenlager</Text>
               </Description>
         </Descriptions>
    </Warehouse>
</Warehouses>
```

I tried implementing some logic in the mapper tool, but i realized, that this mapping cannot be done only using the mapper.
Do you have a suggestion, how to achieve this transformation?

Regards
Adrian

Answer (score 3):

Doing this mapping in a single mapper activity can be done the following way:

[image: xml mapping]

Comment: I think the only thing you don't cover is the lowercase conversion.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't see the lower case. I did an update on the screenshot. Thanks.